# ssh to another machine after sshing via script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have 3 servers,

server1 -> server2 -> server3

Server2 is reachable only via server 1 and server3 via server2.

Every time connection breaks I have to manually login to both the servers.
Is there any way to login and open bash terminal to server3 through this path via a script?

Comment: If you use tcl/expect scripting it should be possible

Comment: You want to take a look at the tunnel feature ssh offers. That _does_ allow you to directly login to the final system with some preparation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem and I have a solution. I use xdotool to emulate keys (and xclip to copy password that is extracted from other file). This script opens ssh connections to list of servers in separate console tabs. Edit it according to Your needs.

```
for IP in $SERVERS
do
    xdotool key ctrl+shift+t type "ssh $USER@$IP"
    xdotool key Return
    sleep 1
    xdotool key ctrl+shift+v
    xdotool key Return

done
```

Script simply iterate over table of servers. It opens new console tab, prints "ssh some_user@some_ip" and next emulate retrun key.
Sleep is used just to make sure script has enought time to connect to server. At the end password is pasted and You enter first server.
One more thing:
dont touch keyboard while script is running. I hope it can help You.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ssh_config file](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5), this will allow you to easily set this up and then directly connect by using `ssh -F ssh_config servername`.

Assuming you're logged in to server_1 and want to connect to server_3 via server_2 it would look something like this:

```
Host server_2
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  Port xxxx
  User server2_user

Host server_3
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  Port xxxx
  ProxyCommand ssh -F ssh_config  server_2
  User server3_user
```

With this you can use `ssh -F ssh_config server_3` and it will connect to server_2 and from there take you directly to server_3.

If you put the ssh_config in the default location you can also omit the `-F ssh_config` part (in the command and the config file) since it will get picked up automatically.

For more information check out [this link](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host), or search the web for 'ssh jumphost', that's a more widely used description for your setup (server 2 is jumphost for server 3 in your case).